# move h1 on a separate line from background image

Tags: html, css

I have `h1` and an image in one of my `div`'s. Currently, image is a background with `h1` written over it. Is it possible to keep both elements in one `div` (than just moving `h1` higher outside `div`) and image as background but to move `h1` higher than background image so it is on its own line?

Result I want to achieve :
[image: result I want to achieve]

```html
    <div class="header">
            <h1>Northside Youth Soccer League</h1>
            <img src="images/nysl_logo.png" alt="Company Logo">
    </div>
```

```css
    .header {
    background-image:url("../images/design2_image1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 300px; 
    position: relative;   


    h1{
    color: #000000;
    font: 40px/60px "Sans", Inconsolata, "Lucida Console", Terminal, "Courier New", Courier;
    text-align:left;
```

Comment: your code looks like you have 2 images - it is not clear what you want to achieve - if it's the result in the picture, then what is the background image for?  Your html as provided with no styling should give you the result in the picture you have attached

Comment: Ya i am also confuse what you want to achieve, because, which html you have that is same as you want to achieve. please clear your question so that we can answer.

Comment: If I understand what it is you are asking this is only possible if you **know** the height of the `h1` in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) of your background image, and for example push it down from the top so that it would appear below your heading.

So if you do something like this:

```css
.header {
    background-position: 0 60px;
    height: 360px; /* Original height + 60px */
}
```

This will place your background on the left side and 60px down from the top - since this is your heading line-height.

This will probably *not* be an ideal solution because your heading is locked to an explicit number of lines. (What happens on mobile screens etc.?)

Also, if the background image needs a certain height, you would have to add 60px to the height of your header container since you moved the background image down this much.

Answer (score 0):

add transform: translateY(-100%); to your h1 styles

```
h1{
color: #000000;
font: 40px/60px "Sans", Inconsolata, "Lucida Console", Terminal, "Courier New", Courier;
text-align:left;
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```